# Majorization of $(5,5,0) $ by $(10,0,0)$

Tags: order-theory, majorization

**[Majorization definition:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization#Geometry_of_majorization)** $x $ is majorized by $y$ iff $x$ is in the convex hull of all the points formed by permuting the components of $y$.

**Question**: $(5,5,0) $ is majorized by $(10,0,0)$ according to the [alternate definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) of majorization given at wikipedia.

My confusion is: the convex hull formed by $(10,0,0)$ is the planar equilateral-triangle with three vertices at $(10,0,0), (0,10,0)$ and $ (0,0,10)$; and $(5,5,0)$ is not the part of this convex set. I see the two definitions contradicting.

Comment: Why do you believe the triangle formed from $(5,5,0)$ is not the middle quarter of the triangle formed from $(10,0,0)$?

Comment: $(5,5,0)$ is not contained in the convex hull (the minimal convex set) because I think that convex hull is planar and not 3D solid. Only if convex hull is 3D solid then $(5,5,0)$ is contained in it,

Comment: The permutations of $(5,5,0)$ are $(5,5,0)$, $(5,0,5)$, and $(0,5,5)$.  This is planar.  (Both triangles are on the plane $x+y+z=10$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $(5,5,0) = 0.5(10,0,0) + 0.5(0,10,0)+0(0,0,10)$, so it is in the convex hull.

Comment: That means the convex hull formed by permuting components of $(10,0,0)$ is not planar but a solid cone?

Comment: @kaka No, it's a planar triangle, but the plane it lives in is the plane $x+y+z=10$; precisely the plane spanned by these three points.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.